# Heroku push error Sass Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I've bben trying to deploy a Ruby application to Heroku.  The application works fine locally but I keep getting this error when I try and deploy.

Being very new to Ruby I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I've removed the the bootstrap-theme.css.map to see if that would make a difference.

I've been trying all week to get this working and keep getting to this point and get no further.

ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
Rails 4.2.0

Any ideas

Thanks

```
Total 1679 (delta 1010), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
    remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
    remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
    remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
    remote:        Installing minitest 5.5.1
    remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
    remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
    remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
    remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
    remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
    remote:        Installing rack 1.6.0
    remote:        Installing mime-types 2.4.3
    remote:        Installing arel 6.0.0
    remote:        Installing ice_nine 0.11.1
    remote:        Installing json 1.8.2
    remote:        Installing bootstrap_form 2.3.0
    remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1
    remote:        Installing execjs 2.4.0
    remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
    remote:        Installing equalizer 0.0.9
    remote:        Installing hashie 3.4.0
    remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.0
    remote:        Installing multi_xml 0.5.5
    remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
    remote:        Using bundler 1.7.12
    remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
    remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
    remote:        Installing sass 3.2.19
    remote:        Installing will_paginate 3.0.7
    remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
    remote:        Installing descendants_tracker 0.0.4
    remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
    remote:        Installing rack-accept 0.4.5
    remote:        Installing rack-mount 0.8.3
    remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
    remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
    remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.1
    remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
    remote:        Installing sprockets 2.12.3
    remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing axiom-types 0.1.1
    remote:        Installing coercible 1.0.0
    remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
    remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.3
    remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing climate_control 0.0.3
    remote:        Installing jbuilder 1.5.3
    remote:        Installing virtus 1.0.4
    remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing protected_attributes 1.0.8
    remote:        Installing cocaine 0.5.7
    remote:        Installing grape 0.11.0
    remote:        Installing paperclip 4.2.1
    remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
    remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.1
    remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.5
    remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
    remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing railties 4.2.0
    remote:        Installing pg 0.18.1
    remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.2.4
    remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
    remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3
    remote:        Installing responders 2.1.0
    remote:        Installing jquery-ui-rails 5.0.3
    remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.5
    remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
    remote:        Installing rails 4.2.0
    remote:        Your bundle is complete!
    remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
    remote:        It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
    remote:        Bundle completed (29.23s)
    remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
    remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
    remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
    remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/config/environments/production.rb:23)
    remote:        rake aborted!
    remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...":3,"sources":[": expected "|", was ""less/normalize..."
    remote:        (in /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/app/assets/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/css/bootstrap.css.map)
    remote:        (sass):1
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1085:in `expected'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1080:in `tok!'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:785:in `attrib_name!'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:753:in `attrib'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:672:in `simple_selector_sequence'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:646:in `_selector'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:619:in `selector'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:603:in `selector_sequence'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:528:in `ruleset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:591:in `block in declaration_or_ruleset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `call'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1123:in `rethrow'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:592:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:554:in `block_child'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:543:in `block_contents'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:535:in `block'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:529:in `ruleset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:553:in `block_child'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:543:in `block_contents'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
    remote:        /tmp/build_4096e4ec1586ed9cc408dfe450ef9328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
    remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
    remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
    remote:  !
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to young-sands-7749.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/young-sands-7749.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/young-sands-7749.git'
```

Comment: CSS syntax errors are ignored in development environment, but not on production. So `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` excute this command this will tell you the error. Then fix that syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem, I run **bundle update** and it helped:

```
Installing spring 1.3.5 (was 1.3.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got the application code to deploy to Heroku.
I had to make sure that the Ruby and Rails version matched those supported by Heroku.  I then followed this guide:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

An issue I still have is around the database data deployment.  The development database was SQLite3 which is not supported by Heroku so I have to migrate the data to a local instance of PostgreSQL. This is proving to be a challenge and have posted another question to try and resolve this issue.

Thanks for the comments. Sontya's was useful to a R on R noobe.